# Universe dictionary item extract first character of attribute in a multivalue field

Tags: dictionary, multivalue, universe

am trying to extract the first character from each subvalue in a record attribute.

Thus far am trying

REUSE(@RECORD<2>);FIELD(@1,'*',1,1)

But it would appear to be returning the first character of the first subvalue.

Know this can be done, but having no luck with it.

Edit record 2 is in the format A*B*C]B*A*D]F*C*C"

Edit 2 , sorry there's an aster (*) between each letter of the array in previous line but can't work out how to show that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it you are looking to do a FIELD operation on a multivalued attribute use FIELDS instead.

```
FIELDS(@RECORD<2>,'*',1)
```

If you are trying to get just the first character, or so any kind of string manipulation for that matter, I will tell you that I have long found that to be somewhat difficult. Upon reflection, the way forward might be using FMTS(), but as I am not sure that is what you are looking for, I will wait to test that out when I have need for it again.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a number of ways to do this but I would use a conversion like this:

OCONVS(@RECORD<2>, 'T1')

This uses the T conversion to text extract the first character.  It is applied to a multivalue by using the OCONVS function.

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.